# Create a workflow to notify manager that item needs to be updated

Tags: 2010, workflow, column

I am trying to create a workflow in SharePoint 2010 to send a notification to a person designated as a manager if an item in a list has not been modified within at least two days. I'm not exactly sure how to calculate the last modified date to find if the difference is 2 days or more. From searching I have found I can't use [Today] to calculate this. Is there another way to calculate the difference without using the [Today] column value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a column called remainder in the list as calculated column and formula as Modified + 2

1. Create a designer workflow to send a notification email
2. In workflow settings click on chekc box start workflow automatically when an item is created
3. condition if any value equals value
   For first value select workflow context and for field select Association:item start on creation
4. next use pause condition pause until date (Current item: Reminder Date field)
5. Condition: If current item field  (Current item: Reminder Date) equals (is greater than or equals) value (Today)
6. Email
7. Log to workflow history.
   Try this approach.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create a view instead that filters items that has not been modified in 2 days and the manager has to checking the page daily.

Comment: Under normal circumstances I would do this, the workflow however was an explicit request.